# Pandas: Keep rows if at least one of them contains certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in Pandas

```
letter  number
------ -------
a       2
a       0
b       1
b       5
b       2
c       1
c       0
c       2
```

I'd like to keep all rows if at least one matching number is 0.
Result would be:

```
letter  number
------ -------
a       2
a       0
c       1
c       0
c       2
```

as b has no matching number being 0

What is the best way to do this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

You need [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby('letter').filter(lambda x: (x['number'] == 0).any())
print (df)
  letter  number
0      a       2
1      a       0
5      c       1
6      c       0
7      c       2
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) where get size of `0` rows and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.groupby('letter')['number'].transform(lambda x: (x == 0).sum()))
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
Name: number, dtype: int64

df = df[df.groupby('letter')['number'].transform(lambda x: (x == 0).sum()) > 0]
print (df)
  letter  number
0      a       2
1      a       0
5      c       1
6      c       0
7      c       2
```

EDIT:

Faster is not use `groupby`, better is [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df['letter'].isin(df.loc[df['number'] == 0, 'letter'])]
print (df1)
  letter  number
0      a       2
1      a       0
5      c       1
6      c       0
7      c       2
```

Comparing with another solution:

```
In [412]: %timeit df[df['letter'].isin(df[df['number'] == 0]['letter'])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 815 µs per loop

In [413]: %timeit df[df['letter'].isin(df.loc[df['number'] == 0, 'letter'])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 657 µs per loop
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Amazing. Thanks ! :)

Comment: I think he knew he needed a filter, what he needed was groupby!

Comment: @CodeMonkey - Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without the `groupby` by working out which letters to keep then using `isin`. I think this is a bit neater personally:

```
>>> letters_to_keep = df[df['number'] == 0]['letter']
>>> df_reduced = df[df['letter'].isin(letters_to_keep)]
>>> df_reduced
  letter  number
0      a       2
1      a       0
5      c       1
6      c       0
7      c       2
```

I suspect this would be faster than doing a `groupby`, that may not be relevant here though! A simple `timeit` would indicate this is the case:

```
>>> %%timeit
... df.groupby('letter').filter(lambda x: (x['number'] == 0).any())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop

>>> %%timeit
... df[df['letter'].isin(df[df['number'] == 0]['letter'])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 820 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly right, `groupby` is slow. I a bit modify your solution for faster one, check my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is perfect combo with boolean indexing - filter by mask and also by column name.